# Building Android project with Ant -- cannot find symbol

Tags: android, ant

I am attempting to build my android project using ant (it runs fine in eclipse).  I run an error with the following build failed line:

```
BUILD FAILED
.../android_sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:680: The following error occurred while executing this line:
.../android_sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:693: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The above java compilation has plenty of errors, all of which are cannot find symbol errors.  Most of these symbols are variables added to the R file.  And some are classes within the project.

I set up the build environment using:

```
android update project --path .
```

My tools and platform_tools are all up-to-date and I'm running on android-7.  I've refreshed the project, ran a clean on the project, and even restarted eclipse.

I'm fairly new to ant and would appreciate any advice.

The build failing output (as requested, I apologize for the formatting issues):

MacBook-Pro:[company]_Android$ ant clean debugBuildfile: [android_path]/build.xml

```
-check-env:
[checkenv] Android SDK Tools Revision 20
[checkenv] Installed at [path]/android_sdks

-setup:
 [echo] Project Name: SplashActivity
 [gettype] Project Type: Application
 [echo] Switching between debug and non debug build: Deleting previous compilation output...
 [delete] Deleting directory [android_path]/bin/classes

-pre-clean:

clean:
 [delete] Deleting directory [android_path]/bin
 [delete] Deleting directory [android_path]/gen
 [getlibpath] Library dependencies:
 [getlibpath] No Libraries
 [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

  ###removed some code#####
 -build-setup:
  [echo] Resolving Build Target for SplashActivity...
  [gettarget] Project Target:   Android 2.1
  [gettarget] API level:        7
  [echo] ----------
  [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
  [mkdir] Created dir: [android_path]/bin
  [mkdir] Created dir: [android_path]/bin/res
  [mkdir] Created dir: [android_path]/gen
  [mkdir] Created dir: [android_path]/bin/classes
  [echo] ----------
  [echo] Resolving Dependencies for SplashActivity...
   [dependency] Ordered libraries:
   [dependency] 
   [dependency] ------------------
   [dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
   [echo] ----------
   [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

 -pre-build:

 -code-gen:
    [mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
    [mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.
    [echo] Handling aidl files...
    [aidl] Found 1 AIDL files.
    [aidl] Compiling 1 AIDL files.
    [echo] ----------
    [echo] Handling RenderScript files...
    [renderscript] No RenderScript files to compile.
    [echo] ----------
    [echo] Handling Resources...
    [aapt] Generating resource IDs...
    [echo] ----------
    [echo] Handling BuildConfig class...
    [buildconfig] Generating BuildConfig class.

-pre-compile:

-compile:
[javac] Compiling 263 source files to [android_path]/bin/classes
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/AbstractFirstBaseActivity.java:447: warning: unmappable character for encoding UTF-8

#####removed a lot of similar warnings######

[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/models/[company]Match.java:14: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class MatchExpiryComparator
[javac] location: package com.[company].firstbase.util
[javac] import com.[company].firstbase.util.MatchExpiryComparator;
[javac]                                  ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/models/[company]Match.java:21: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class MatchExpiryComparator
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.models.[company]Match
[javac]     public static MatchExpiryComparator EXPIRATION_SORT_COMPARATOR = new MatchExpiryComparator();
[javac]                   ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:12: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class DashboardActivity
[javac] location: package com.[company].firstbase
[javac] import com.[company].firstbase.DashboardActivity;
[javac]                             ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/FirstBaseApplication.java:178: warning: non-varargs call of varargs method with inexact argument type for last parameter;
[javac] cast to java.lang.Object for a varargs call
[javac] cast to java.lang.Object[] for a non-varargs call and to suppress this warning
[javac]                         facebookData.put(key, Utils.stringJoin(",", entries));
[javac]                                                                     ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/misc/Panel.java:189: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable panelHandle
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.R.id
[javac]         mHandle = findViewById(R.id.panelHandle);
[javac]                                    ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/misc/Panel.java:193: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable panelContent
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.R.id
[javac]         mContent = findViewById(R.id.panelContent);
[javac]                                     ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/models/[company]Match.java:21: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class MatchExpiryComparator
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.models.[company]Match
[javac]     public static MatchExpiryComparator EXPIRATION_SORT_COMPARATOR = new MatchExpiryComparator();
[javac]                                                                          ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/models/[company]Match.java:56: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable USERS_USERID
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.db.DbHelper
[javac]         this.userID = Utils.descryptForDB(c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbHelper.USERS_USERID)));
[javac]                                                                                       ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/models/[company]Match.java:57: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable USERS_USERNAME
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.db.DbHelper
[javac]         this.username = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbHelper.USERS_USERNAME));
[javac]                                                                     ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/models/[company]Match.java:58: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable USERS_PHOTO
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.db.DbHelper
[javac]         this.photoURI = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(DbHelper.USERS_PHOTO));
[javac]                                                                     ^

 #######Removed a lot of similar errors ##########


[javac]                                                                            ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:21: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable widget_layout
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.R.layout
[javac]             RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
[javac]                                                                                   ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:23: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable DashboardActivity
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.widget.[company]Widget
[javac]             int count = DashboardActivity.mMatchesCalloutCount+DashboardActivity.mConnectionsCalloutCount;
[javac]                         ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:23: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable DashboardActivity
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.widget.[company]Widget
[javac]             int count = DashboardActivity.mMatchesCalloutCount+DashboardActivity.mConnectionsCalloutCount;
[javac]                                                                ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:23: incompatible types
[javac] found   : java.lang.String
[javac] required: int
[javac]             int count = DashboardActivity.mMatchesCalloutCount+DashboardActivity.mConnectionsCalloutCount;
[javac]                                                               ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:27: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable callout
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.R.id
[javac]                 views.setTextViewText(R.id.callout, count+"");
[javac]                                           ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:28: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable callout
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.R.id
[javac]                 views.setViewVisibility(R.id.callout, View.VISIBLE);
[javac]                                             ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:31: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable callout
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.R.id
[javac]                 views.setViewVisibility(R.id.callout, View.GONE);
[javac]                                             ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:34: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : class DashboardActivity
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.widget.[company]Widget
[javac]             Intent intent = new Intent(context, DashboardActivity.class);
[javac]                                                 ^
[javac] [android_path]/src/com/[company]/firstbase/widget/[company]Widget.java:37: cannot find symbol
[javac] symbol  : variable widget_heart
[javac] location: class com.[company].firstbase.R.id
[javac]             views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_heart, pendingIntent);
[javac]                                               ^
[javac] Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
[javac] Note: Some input files use unchecked or unsafe operations.
[javac] Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[javac] 40 errors
[javac] 21 warnings
```

BUILD FAILED
[path]/android_sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:680: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[path]/android_sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:693: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.

Total time: 6 seconds

Comment: Is the project using any library project or external libraries? Why do you speak of Eclipse if you do ant building - you can do all the work from command line (so that you reduce one edge of error proneness).

Comment: I'm using a lot of libraries/external libraries.  They are all linked and I'm not having problem with those perse.  Also, just spoke of eclipse to show that it was running on eclipse and I know it should run.

Comment: What you mean linked? As far as Eclipse is concerned you can add them to the build path with right clicks and stuff. However, ant reads all external libraries from the libs folder. Android Library projects also require special care.

Comment: All of these libraries are in the libs folder.

Comment: Is the command you run `ant clean release`?

Comment: I was actually trying `ant clean debug` but I tried `ant` `ant clean` `ant release` and `ant clean release` to be safe.  I didn't add anything to the build.xml file.  Nor even make my changes in an build.properties file yet.  I haven't set it up with a signature yet either (I'm not sure if that'll change anything).

Comment: Can I then get the first 50 or so lines of errors after you run the compilation?

Comment: Yup, also I appreciate you working this out with me.  I've been stuck on this one for quite some time.

Comment: Hmm that's very weird. You seem to find most of the classes, you just do not find the fields. I can say I have done similar builds dozens of times and it was always as you describe. The only difference is that I build for API level 8, not 7. Can you try with 8? (btw my next post will be tomorrow as I head for sleep now).

Comment: I'll try 8.  I was kinda hoping I was missing something completely obvious.  For when you wake up, should I be worried about this line in the output: `[getlibpath] Library dependencies:
 [getlibpath] No Libraries`

Comment: FYI, did not work with android-8.

Comment: you shouldn't be worried by `[getlibpath] Library dependencies: [getlibpath] No Libraries`. Here only referenced Android library projects are considered. You do not use such.

Comment: the only justification i can give is that you use some old files during the compilation. I cna not tell why is that though. Can you tell me the system path to `com.[company].firstbase.util.MatchExpiryComparator`.

Comment: Figured it out.  I was excluding a good number of classes on my buildpath on Eclipse, so I just deleted them, and it worked fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out:

I was excluding files on my buildpath on Eclipse.  Obviously, this wasn't the case on Ant.  Instead of adding this large number of files on my Ant file, I just deleted these files and things worked out.

Comment: i am also getting the same error what you had mentioned in this post.can you please elaborate your solution

Comment: in eclipse, I excluded a few files from my build path.  The ant file did not know to ignore these files.  So, rather than manually excluding them in the ant build, I removed these useless files from the build altogether.  Afterwards, it was able to build just fine.

Comment: Just to make it more clear for anyone else who is facing this problem. Just delete any folders/files you have added manually into your project's directory and aren't included in your build path

Comment: `ant clean` then `ant debug`

Comment: I had eclipse open when building with ant and ant clean was not sufficient for me. I had to clean in eclipse and deactivate build automatically. And then use ant clean release to get it working again.